# Pass value from parent window(client side value) to popup window in master page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In master page footer

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnlcontact" runat="server" OnClientClick="return PopupFeedback()">Contact admin/Feedback</asp:LinkButton>
```

Popup window open function

```
function PopupFeedback() {

            var currentURL = window.location.href;          
            //alert(currentURL);
                window.open('/PopupFeedback.aspx', "_blank", "WIDTH=650,HEIGHT=500,scrollbars=yes, menubar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no", "PopupFeedback");       

            return false;
        }
```

I got current page url, trying to send url to popup window from the screen user clicks contact.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, is this what you need

```
function PopupFeedback() {    
            var currentURL = window.location.href;          
            window.open('PopupFeedback.aspx?myvar='+currentUrl, "_blank", "WIDTH=650,HEIGHT=500,scrollbars=yes, menubar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no", "PopupFeedback");      
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying to send currentURL value to Popupfeedback.aspx page

Comment: you could pass that over in the url, something like PopupFeedback.aspx?myvar=currentUrl